# Focus issue while tab press

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have three buttons `Cancel`, `Submit` & `Reset` in a form and a close button in the titlebar. When I press tab button it focuses close button of the form, next press switch the focus to the first button and again on next tab click its focusing back to the close button instead of shifting focus to next buttons. Below is the code.

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',    
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],    
    autoShow: true,
    title: "Test",
    width: 350,    
    items: {
        xtype: 'form',
        buttonAlign:'center',
        buttons: [
            {
                text   : 'Cancel'
            }, {
                text    : 'Submit'
            }, {
                text    : 'Reset'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Test');
```

I can change the focus by using arrow keys but I guess it should be focused by tab press only. Any hints please. I am using Extjs 6 classic.

[image]

Fiddle link [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2u12)

Comment: In which element you are binding your close button?

Comment: @Rajesh its a default button on form panel

Comment: Create a fiddle with the above code, and in firefox, when I press tab the first button that is focus is the `Cancel`, the close panel button is never focused

Comment: @MatheusHatje https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2u12 here is the fiddle link. I have shared the screenshot displaying focus on close button. didnt tested on firefox as i am using chrome.

Comment: It seems to be a "bug" with the Extjs Version, I created a fiddle in 7.0 version and couldn't reproduce the issue, my advice would be to use keymaps, and or focus/focusleave listeners to select whatever component you want to be focused

Comment: @MatheusHatje yeah, i observed that but as of now i cant upgrade so have to find the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Well, appears to be a bug. One workaround is to make a custom button panel, the focus still goes to the close button but it cycles to all the buttons, take a look:

```
Ext.define('Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    autoShow: true,
    title: "Test",
    width: 350,

    items: [{

        //Your content panel
        xtype: 'panel',
        padding:20,
        height: 300,
        html: 'My Content Panel'

    }, {

        //Custom button panel
        xtype: 'panel',
        padding: 10,
        layout: {
            align: 'middle',
            pack: 'center',
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
            margin: '0 2 0 0',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Cancel'
        }, {
            margin: '0 2 0 0',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Submit'
        }, {
            margin: '0 2 0 0',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Reset'
        }]
    }],

});

Ext.create('Test');
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: yeah its working but not sure if the approach is correct. anyways thanks for the workaround.